# What's the nid in jstack on MacOS

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

On Linux/HotSpot VM, `top -H` can list all threads of some java process, hence the thread id of busy thread can be spotted, so I can use that thread id to find the java thread in jstack output (the nid in jstack is the hex translation of thread id in top -H).

While Hotspot VM implementation on MacOS platform uses `pthread_t` as `nid` when using jstack to get Java threads stats, and there is nothing similar to `top -H` on MacOS. So is there any way to find the "busy" Java thread without MXBean?

Or can anyone tell me on MacOS how I can find the busy Java thread's 'nid', according to which I can find corresponding Java thread by jstack?

Answer (score 0):

A small correction: on macOS, `nid` is not `pthread_t`, but rather a thread port as obtained by `pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_t)`.

Anyway, there is no an equivalent of `top -H` on macOS, unfortunately. But you don't need one, if you just want to find a busy Java thread. Use a Java profiler instead.

Here is how to do this with [`async-profiler`](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/):

```
./profiler.sh -d 10 -t -f profile.svg PID
```

This means: profile the Java process `PID` for ten seconds (`-d 10`) in threaded mode (`-t`) and save the output as a Flame Graph to `profile.svg`. You won't even need `jstack` - the profile will already highlight the hottest thread(s) with their Java stack traces.

[image: Flame Graph]

As an alternative to a Flame Graph, you may choose a "traditional" tree view
by specifying `-f profile.html` instead of `-f profile.svg`.